# PHP - check user credentials after page (re)load

Tags: php, mysql

If a user logs in on my site, relevant checks are undergone to log them in, including creating a $_SESSION, however as they browse the site it will obviously check they are still logged in upon loading the next page they navigate to.

At the moment, the code for this check is:

```
$users = blueFactory::create('blueUsers',$db, $core);

session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login']['username']) && isset($_SESSION['login']['hash']))
{
    $userN = $_SESSION['login']['username'];
    $userH = $_SESSION['login']['hash'];
    if($users->CheckUser($userN, $userH) > 0)
    {
        define('LOGGED_IN',true);
        define('USER_ID',$users->Name2id($userN));
        define('USER_NAME',$users->GrabUserVar(USER_ID,"username"));
        define('USER_HASH',$userH);
    }
    else {
        define('LOGGED_IN',false);
        define('USER_ID',0);
        define('USER_NAME','Guest');
        define('USER_HASH',0);
        session_destroy();
    }
}
else {
    define('LOGGED_IN',false);
    define('USER_ID',0);
    define('USER_NAME','Guest');
    define('USER_HASH',0);
}
```

The $users->checkUser() function will check the database each time the page is reloaded, whether the session information is correct.

My concern is, I feel like there is a better way to write the above code, however I have no clue how it would be done! I'm looking for better ways to write the login checks while the user navigates the site (and are logged in).

Thanks for your help (in advance!)

Comment: This might just be preference, but using `define()` might not be a good option. From experience, `define()` is used for something that won't change. Why not make all those a variable, which can be accessed from any code requiring or including this code?

Answer (score 0):

Verify if your CONSTANT is already defined, like:

```
...

if (defined('LOGGED_IN')) { // exists?
   if (!LOGGED_IN) { // if false, keep doing ..
... code and more code ...
}

...
```